# How can I remove a certain amount of tabs in String with js?

Tags: javascript, string

The goal is to remove 4 tabs in front in each line with the use of JS.

**Current String:**

```
            .mockuptext{
                max-width: 40%;
                min-width: 150px;
                max-height: 70%;
                margin: 3rem;
                padding: calc(1rem + 30px) 1.5rem 1rem 1rem;                  
            }
```

**Desired String:**

```
.mockuptext{
    max-width: 40%;
    min-width: 150px;
    max-height: 70%;
    margin: 3rem;
    padding: calc(1rem + 30px) 1.5rem 1rem 1rem;                  
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? How are you approaching the problem Tom?

Comment: I've tried to replace the innerHTML like: node.innerHTML.replace(/\t/g, '') but it didn't do anything

Comment: So is this string going to be pasted inside a textbox or something like that?

Comment: Your code works for me https://jsfiddle.net/xz0h2ypd/ but I am not sure where you are trying to remove these tabs from, so I just used a textarea. You need to provide a working example of your problem for people here to be able to help you.

Comment: I would like to use a code element like so: https://jsfiddle.net/tmlrd/p2e3sc0q/12/ 
the code element is for another library I want to use

Comment: In your jsfiddle, you use "node.querySelector('code').value", but shloud use "document" instead of "node" and "innerHTML" instead of "value"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are possibly multiple ways of doing this. Since you did not share the context/use-case of of this problem, I am assuming that you already have a means of accessing the string and storing it in a variable. If you have that, you can refer to the code below.

You can use regular expressions to find and replace occurrences of 4 tabs at the beginning of each line.

The Regex that I am using to match 4 tabs at the beginning of each line is `\^\t{4}\gm`:

- The `gm` flag at the end of the regex stands for global (i.e. return all matches, not just the first one) and multiline; the multiline flag tells the regex matcher to perform the match at each line instead of the beginning of the string.
- The `^` matches the beginning of the line
- The `\t{4}` matches 4 tab characters.
- Overall, the regex is saying "Find occurrences of 4 tabs starting at the beginning of each line in a string"

To actually modify the string, I am using the `replace` method. which takes a regex and replaces all matches of the regex with the second argument of the method.

```js
let s = `\
\t\t\t\t.mockuptext{\n
\t\t\t\t\tmax-width: 40%;\n
\t\t\t\t\tmin-width: 150px;\n
\t\t\t\t\tmax-height: 70%;\n
\t\t\t\t\tmargin: 3rem;\n
\t\t\t\t\tpadding: calc(1rem + 30px) 1.5rem 1rem 1rem;\n
\t\t\t\t}\n
`;
console.log(s);

console.log(s.replace(/^\t{4}/gm, ""))
```

You can also create a function to encapsulate the wrapping like:

```
function replace4Tabs(s) {
  return s.replace(/^\t{4}/gm, "")
}
```

and if you have an html element that you want to update, you can use

`elem.innerHTML = replace4Tabs(elem.innerHTML);`

PS:
If you are new to Regex, I have found Regex101 to be a great resource. It will highlight matches as you type and provide an explanation of how Regex is matching https://regex101.com/r/7SxOEM/1